# How do I change the default EOL settings/encoding of new files in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, line-endings

I'm trying to change the encoding of new files in Notepad++ to always be Unix/OSX, but even after setting this in the preferences, new files always default to Dos/Windows.

The way I create new files is this: I'm connected to a remote server via FTP, and I am right clicking a directory, and then choosing "Create new file". I enter its name, which usually is "something.tpl". Then I will double click that newly created file from the directory browser to edit it. It will open up, and its encoding is "Dos/Windows ANSI". I want it to be "Unix/OSX". Why is the setting I applied from the preferences section for new document encoding not affecting this new file?

When I create a new file by going File -> New... then it will have a Unix encoding. Why does my setting apply to new files created via this method but not the previous method I described via being connected to a remote server and right clicking a directory and selecting "Create new file"? It seems both methods fall under the category of creating a new file.

Comment: Do you mean NppFTP plugin? This sounds like a problem with plugin, rather than N++ (I haven't used that plugin myself). If it is, you might want to send a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found a NppFTP defect. You can report it in [Npp FTP bugtracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/nppftp/bugs/). (Before, you can check if someone didn't report it already.)

It also looks you have found a workaround, too, by creating a file without Npp FTP and then uploading it to FTP server. I recommend you stick with a workaround until the Npp FTP defect is fixed.